# Linux: Counting occurrences with egrep

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

I am doing pattern recognition in files using grep/egrep command. I wish to find all the occurrences of the string M8, m8, P8 or d8. I was planning on doing the following:

`grep -c '[MmPd]8' myFile >> outputFile`

However, the -c option counts the number of lines on which the pattern appears. I have files which have more than one instance of these strings on a line. Is there a way to count the total number of times it occurs, rather than the total number of lines it occurs on?

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU grep` you can use `grep -o` and pipe that to `wc`:

```
grep -o pattern input.file | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the length of this script in your shell,
but the following idea should work:

grep "M8" myFile >> out.M8

grep "m8" myFile >> out.m8

grep "P8" myFile >> out.P8

grep "d8" myFile >> out.d8

wc -l out.*